# Trying to call a Future<void> function() in onPressed option in Flutter

Tags: flutter, function, dart, unityads, flutter-onpressed

I am trying to show an Unity Ad when a button is pressed. I tried a few things but I can't fix it.

Here are my code snippets:

main.dart ->

```
Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await AdManager.showIntAd();
                            },
                          child: Text('Doniraj'),
                      )),),
```

AdManager.dart ->

```
  static Future<void> showIntAd() async {
   UnityAds.showVideoAd(
    placementId: AdHelper.interstitialId,
    onStart: (placementId) => print('Video Ad $placementId started'),
    onClick: (placementId) => print('Video Ad $placementId click'),
    onSkipped: (placementId) => print('Video Ad $placementId skipped'),
    onComplete: (placementId) async {
      await loadUnityIntAd();
    },
    onFailed: (placementId, error, message) async {
      await loadUnityIntAd();
    });
```

}

I appreciate your suggestions

Comment: try `return UnityAds.showVideoAd....`

Comment: This worked. I don't know exactly why but it fixed my problem, there was also an error in the hierarchy of the widget that caused a problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: You are welcome. You need to return the return value of a future function from an async function if you use `await` when calling it.